# Transform list of values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a list of strings (my actual list is **much** longer):

```
Animals = ["Dog", "1", "F", "2",
           "Cat", "M",
           "Horse", "40", "D", "9", 
           "Human", "50", "E",
           "Zebra", "50", "4", "P", "A", "19",
           "Dog", "60", "1"]
```

If it's any use, I also have list of the animal names themselves:

```
Animal_names = ["Dog", "Cat", "Horse", "Human", "Zebra"]
```

What I want to do is transform this so that it becomes the following (a list of lists starting with animal names and the proceeding values that follow the names and end before the next name appears in **Animals_names**):

```
[["Dog", "1", "F", "2"],
 ["Cat", "M"],
 ["Horse", "40", "D", "9"], 
 ["Human", "50", "E"],
 ["Zebra", "50", "4", "P", "A", "19"],
 ["Dog", "60", "1"]]
```

Is there some way to get this easily?

Comment: post your code ...

Comment: How long is *much longer*? It looks like you need to traverse the list once, a `for` loop isn't that bad.

Comment: How do you know when to stop reading values for a given animal? For instance, the first `Dog` has a length of 4, while the second has a length of 3.

Comment: @AnoopRDesai when the next value exists in ```Animal_names```.

Comment: It may be beneficial to build a dictionary keyed on animal names instead of a list of lists, that way you have a way to query the dictionary using the `Animal_names` list you provided.

Comment: Define "easily".

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest  Apologies. I had some extremely messy for loop and wasn't sure if it was worth posting. I thought the visuals were better for showing what I was asking about.

Comment: @QuangHoang About a couple million elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short approach (assuming the input list starts with an existent *animal name*):

```
res = []
for a in animals:
    if a in animal_names:
        res.append([a])
    else:
        res[-1].append(a)
print(res)
```

The output:

```
[['Dog', '1', 'F', '2'], ['Cat', 'M'], ['Horse', '40', 'D', '9'], ['Human', '50', 'E'], ['Zebra', '50', '4', 'P', 'A', '19'], ['Dog', '60', '1']]
```

---

Or another way without `else` branch - but that will cause a larger number of `append` calls (therefore should be considered as a ***slower*** one):

```
res = []
for a in animals:
    if a in animal_names:
        res.append([])
    res[-1].append(a)
```

Comment: You don't need the `else` if you just append `[]` to `res` each time.

Comment: @chepner In which case the preceding line would be `res.append(list())`, otherwise the animal name would be appended twice.

Comment: Right, I was a bit too terse. Use `res.append([])` when you see a recognized animal name,  then `res[-1].append(a)` can be called unconditionally on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @chepner, by the way, your suggestion will lead to 28 `append` calls in comparing to 22 calls of the initial approach

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I'll worry about that when it becomes the bottleneck in my overall program :)

Comment: @chepner, anyway, I should have mentioned that - just a matter of "deep analysis". that's ok

Answer (score 1):

Create a new array and fill it with values until it reaches a value that exists in `Animal_names`, then append, clear, and repeat.

```py
array = []
sub_array = []

for item in Animals:

  # Check if the item is an animal name. If it is, add the previous animal to array
  if item in Animal_names:
    if len(sub_array) != 0:
      array.append(sub_array)
      sub_array = []

  sub_array.append(item)

array.append(sub_array)  # get the last animal too
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be a feasible solution :D. It consists on looping over the elements in the big list and start a new List every time you find a new animal.

```
final_list=[]
animal_list=[]
for animal in Animals:
    if animal in Animal_names:
        if len(animal_list):
            final_list.append(animal_list)
        animal_list=[animal]
    else:
        animal_list.append(animal)

final_list.append(animal_list)
final_list
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution with `zip` but it needs the initial loop for finding indices.

```
animal_indices = [
    i 
    for i, name in enumerate(animals)
    if name in animal_names
]
animal_structured = [
    animals[i:j]
    for i, j in zip(animal_indices, animal_indices[1:]+[len(animals)])
]
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of data? Then consider using `numpy` if speed is issue. I would do it following way:

```
import numpy as np
animals = np.array(["Dog", "1", "F", "2", "Cat", "M", "Horse", "40", "D", "9", "Human", "50", "E", "Zebra", "50", "4", "P", "A", "19", "Dog", "60", "1"])
animal_names = np.array(["Dog", "Cat", "Horse", "Human", "Zebra"])
split_at = [inx for inx,i in enumerate(animals) if i in animal_names and inx>0]
output = np.split(animals,split_at) # now output is list of np.arrays
output_list = [list(a) for a in output] # conversion to list of lists
print(output_list)
```

Output:

```
[['Dog', '1', 'F', '2'], ['Cat', 'M'], ['Horse', '40', 'D', '9'], ['Human', '50', 'E'], ['Zebra', '50', '4', 'P', 'A', '19'], ['Dog', '60', '1']]
```

Cost of this approach is that you have to install `numpy` to make it work, gain is that it *might* be faster, especially visible for large amount of data, so if you care about processing time, I suggest running some time-comparing tests of various approaches *with data similar in size to your desired use case*.